# Error converting date or time from character string

Tags: sql

I want to inserd data to my DB and I have 2 errors:

1)

```
insert EmployeesInfo
(ID, MartialStatus, BirthDate, [Address], Phone)
values
(1, 'Не женат', '08/15/1970', 'Викторкая 16/7', '(067)4564489'),
(2, 'Женат',    '09/09/1985', 'Малинская 15', '(050)0564585'),
(3, 'Не женат', '12/11/1990', 'Победы 16, 145', '(068)4560409'),
(4, 'Не женат', '01/11/1988', 'Антонова 11', '(066)4664466'),
(5, 'Замужем',  '08/08/1990', 'Руденко 10, 7', '(093)4334493'),
(6, 'Замужем',  '01/10/1994', 'Просвещения 7', '(063)4114141')
go
```

*Error converting date or time from character string.*

2)

```
insert Stocks
(ProductID, Qty)
values
(1, 20),
(2, 10),
(3, 7),
(4, 8),
(5, 9),
(6, 5),
(7, 12),
(8, 54),
(9, 8),
(10, 7)
go
```

*INSERT statement conflict with FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Stocks__ProductI__6FE99F9F". The conflict occurred in the database 'InternatShopDB', table 'dbo.Products', column 'ID'.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error converting date or time from character string.

Use standard datetime formats.  Either `'19700815'` or `'1970-08-15'`.

> INSERT statement conflict with FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Stocks__ProductI__6FE99F9F". The conflict occurred in the database 'InternatShopDB', table 'dbo.Products', column 'ID'.

Make sure that every `product` that is inserted into the `stocks` table exists in the `products` table.  Unrecognized products will cause an error.